# Dúvida em diagrama de classes

Tags: python, mvc, django, diagrama

Quais os passos para a criação de um diagrama de classes de um projeto feito com Django? Como posso representar MVC no diagrama? Meu projeto tem apenas uma classe Post:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    content = models.TextField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Também criei as seguintes views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .forms import PostForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte = timezone.now()).order_by('published_date').reverse()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render (request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})

def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.published_date = timezone.now()
        post.save()
        return redirect('blog.views.post_list')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_create.html', {'form': form})

def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.save()
        return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def post_delete(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.delete()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_delete.html')
```

Na tentativa de construir um diagrama fiz apenas isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode postar os códigos no lugar da imagem? Ajuda a quem pode te ajudar.

Comment: @Florida Desculpa, já editei com os códigos usados.

Comment: Acho que a sua pergunta está meio equivocada. 
"Quais os passos para a criação de um diagrama de classes de um projeto feito com Django? "
Um diagrama de classes pode ser implementado em qualquer linguagem orientada a objetos.
Você faz uma análise do seu estudo de caso, faz os diagramas e DEPOIS você programa. Seja em django, java, php ou o que for. Estude um pouco de UML. Isso irá te ajudar na criação do diagrama de classe.

Comment: Você deve criar seu modelo inicialmente independente de frameworks..
Seu modelo deve ser o núcleo do seu sistema, inicialmente usando diagrama de classes ou outro ( atividade , fluxograma ) , com o seu modelo pronto , ai sim pode portá-lo para frameworks quaisquer..